# How to disable apparmor for Chromium snap? (Ubuntu 20.04)

Tags: snap, chromium, apparmor

When I type:

`sudo apparmor_status`

these 2 profiles are shown as enforce:

`snap.chromium.chromedriver`

`snap.chromium.chromium`

When I type:

`sudo aa-complain /var/lib/snapd/apparmor/profiles/snap.chromium.chromium`

I get this message:

`Profile for /var/lib/snapd/apparmor/profiles/snap.chromium.chromium not found, skipping`

I want to remove the Chromium apparmor profiles from [enforce] because I'm pretty sure it's interfering with u2f (my USB device is usable in it's desktop app, but not in Chromium). I'm using the default Chromium version that gets installed in Ubuntu 20.04 (installed using Synaptic).

Comment: You don't give the profile-location to `aa-complain`, you give the name of executable/profile - should be `aa-complain snap.chromium.chromium`  in your case, if you need to explicitly give the profile location, use `-d/--dir`, e.g. `aa-complain snap.chromium.chromium -d /var/lib/snapd/apparmor/profiles`

Comment: I tried this but get this error: sudo aa-complain snap.chromium.chromedriver --dir /var/lib/snapd/apparmor/profiles
ERROR: Include file /var/lib/snapd/apparmor/profiles/tunables/global not found